# Sum values are inflated when I join another table

Tags: sql

I have two queries that return the result sets I want, it is one row per user per day.  The problem is that when I try to join the two queries, by userid, I get inflated results because the user is in the table multiple times for each day.  How do I join them and avoid having the inflated results?

```
**Query 1**

SELECT AAL.UserID
     , SUM(AAL.Dur)/60 AS 'LIM'
     , SUM(CASE When AAL.DUR = 'av' then AAL.Dur/60
                Else 0 END) AS 'AVAIL'
FROM WG
INNER JOIN AAL
   on WG.UserID=AAL.UserID
   and WG.SiteID=AAL.SiteID 
WHERE WG.WG = 'OP'
AND DATEDIFF(day,AAL.Date,GETDATE()) = 1
GROUP BY AAL.UserID


**Query 2**

SELECT R.UserID
     , SUM(CASE When R.StID = 4 then 1
                Else 0 End) AS 'Rf Ct'
FROM R
INNER JOIN WG
   on R.UserID = WG.UserID  
WHERE WG.WG = 'OP'
AND DATEDIFF(day,R.Date,GETDATE()) = 1
GROUP BY R.UserID


**JOIN ATTEMPT**

SELECT AAL.UserID
    , SUM(AAL.Dur)/60 AS 'LIM'
    , SUM(CASE When AAL.DUR = 'av' then AAL.Dur/60
               Else 0 END) AS 'AVAIL'
    , SUM(CASE When R.StID = 4 then 1
               Else 0 End) AS 'Rf Ct' 
FROM WG 
INNER JOIN AAL 
   on WG.UserID=AAL.UserID
   and WG.SiteID=AAL.SiteID
INNER JOIN R
   on AAL.UserID=R.UserID
WHERE WG.WG = 'OP'
AND DATEDIFF(day,AAL.Date,GETDATE()) = 1
GROUP BY AAL.UserID
```

Comment: Can you show how you've attempted to join them?

Comment: This was what I had when I joined my queries and the results ended up of course much higher because the users have multiple records in each table.

Comment: And I hit enter too soon.  Sorry here it is:                                       
SELECT AAL.UserID, SUM(AAL.Dur)/60 AS 'LIM', SUM(CASE When AAL.DUR = 'av' then AAL.Dur/60 Else 0 END) AS 'AVAIL', SUM(CASE When R.StID = 4 then 1 Else 0 End) AS 'Rf Ct'
FROM WG INNER JOIN AAL on WG.UserID=AAL.UserID and WG.SiteID=AAL.SiteID INNER JOIN R on AAL.UserID=R.UserID
WHERE WG.WG = 'OP' AND DATEDIFF(day,AAL.Date,GETDATE()) = 1
GROUP BY AAL.UserID

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `WB` in the query.  So, just use `exists` or `in`:

```
SELECT R.UserID, SUM(CASE When R.StID = 4 then 1 Else 0 End) AS 'Rf Ct'
FROM R 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, R.Date, GETDATE()) = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WB WHERE R.UserID = WG.UserID AND WG.WG = 'OP') 
GROUP BY R.UserID;
```

You should understand the reason why the number gets multiplied -- multiple rows in `WG` correspond to a single `R.ID`.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this doesn't help, this query runs fine on it's own, the WG table is not the one with multiples, it is when I join the two queries, the AAL table.